# Object BindingSource not appearing under "Project Data Source"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, data-binding, objectdatasource

Trying (and failing) to get Visual Studio 2012 Express to recognise a custom object databinding source in my code.

I've created and implemented the custom data binding class:

```
public class MarketDataBindingSource : BindingList<MarketDataDisplay> 
{
    public MarketDataBindingSource(Control parent) { Parent = parent; }
    //etc ...
}
```

Works fine from code

```
        dataGridView1.DataSource = new MarketDataBindingSource(dataGridView1);
```

However, if I try to browse from the form designer, Choose Data Source, Add Project Data Source, Object, I do not see anything in my own assembly (only objects in referenced assemblies).

How do I get my assembly/DataSource to be recognised by the editor?